# Let $a_n$ be a sequence defined by: $a_n = \min(m)$ $s.t.$ $\sum_{i = 1}^m \sqrt i > n^2$. Does $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to show convergence (Or divergence) of the following sum:

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence defined by:
>
> $a_n = \min(m)$ $s.t.$ $\sum_{i = 1}^m \sqrt i > n^2$.
>
> Does $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges?

If we define $b_n = \min(m)$ $s.t.$ $\sum_{i = 1}^m \ i > n^2$, We get $b_n > n$, since  $\sum_{i = 1}^ni = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} < n^2$, So $a_n > n$ for sure.

But im not sure how evaluate  $a_n$ any further.

Any hints will be appericiated.

Comment: Compare $\sum_{i = 1}^m \sqrt i$ with $\int_1^{m}\sqrt x dx$.

Comment: It can be shown that $a_n\ge cn^{-4/3}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc What brought you to this specific comparison?

Comment: Note that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a monotone increasing function, thus for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$
\int_{i-1}^{i} \sqrt{x} dx<\sqrt{i}<\int_{i}^{i+1} \sqrt{x} dx
$$
Now sum over $i$ and you'll get a sharp approximation.

Comment: The sum $\sum_{i=1}^m\sqrt{i}$ behaves like $ cm^{3/2}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a>b>0$ we have
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\ge a^2(a-b)$$  $$a-b={a^2-b^2\over a+b}\ge {a^2-b^2\over 2a}$$ Hence for $a=i^{1/2}$ and $b=(i-1)^{1/2}$ we get
$$i^{3/2}-(i-1)^{3/2}\ge i [i^{1/2}-(i-1)^{1/2}]\ge {1\over 2} i^{1/2}$$ Adding the terms gives
$$\displaystyle 2m^{3/2}\ge \sum_{i=1}^m i^{1/2}$$ If the sum is greater than $n^2,$ then $2m^{3/2}\ge n^2, $ which implies $m\ge 2^{-1}n^{4/3}. $ Hence $$a_n\ge {1\over 2}n^{4/3}$$

**Remark** The estimate is optimal concerning the exponent $4/3,$ that means $a_n\le cn^{4/3}.$ To this end it suffices to apply the inequalities (for $a>b>0$)$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\le 3a^2(a-b)$$  $$a-b={a^2-b^2\over a+b}\le {a^2-b^2\over a}$$

Comment: Thus, $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a_n }}}  \le 2^{3/2} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n^{4/3} }  =  + \infty 
$$ which is inconclusive. You need an upper bound for $a_n$ of a similar character. Also $
2m^{3/2}  \ge n^2  \Rightarrow m \ge 2^{ - 2/3} n^{4/3}$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks. I do not need upper bound of $a_n$. Who cares about  lower bound of $1/a_n$ ?  There were obvious misprints at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yes, with the corrected bound, the lower bound solves the problem. May I add that the power of $2$ should be $-2/3$ and not $-3/2$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks. I have replaced the constant by $2^{-1}$ which satisfies $2^{-2/3}>2^{-1}>2^{-3/2}$